# Radiobuttons do not behave correctly: GroupBoxes have no effect; RB selection jumps from one GB to another

Tags: radio-button, firemonkey, c++builder, groupbox

FMX, C++Builder community: I have a big problem with TRadioButtons and TGroupBox. I have a form with 2 (or more) TGroupboxes, in which I placed several TRadioButtons each. I can only have 1 (one) selected at a time (design mode and/or run mode), and the selected radiobuttons states jumps from one TGroupBox to another ... I spent hours and days to figure out what could be the reason; nothing. Started several new test projects (FMX), and the same happens. Impossible to select several buttons from different group boxes. Everything happens like if I have NO groupbox in the form. Any idea ? Do I have missed something ? Or re-install ? many thanks.

Comment: For each button in a group box you need to give a unique name to the GroupName property of the Radio button eg. if you have 3 radio buttons in group box 1, set GroupName to Group1, all the buttons in a second group box, Group2 etc. when you do this, the buttons will act the way you want.

Comment: Thank you very much; it works !. However I'm asking myself why this. With VCL I did not have this behaviour, and once a component is in a container, it is automatically working as planned. So with FMX, can I understand that a radiobutton could be attached to a group, and being outside of the group ? That sounds strange. I tried, and it worked partially...